# MAUI.NET update binding on lost focus alike

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui, lost-focus

**introduction:**

Using MAUI.NET with MVVM architecture, but MVVM can be sacrifice (this need is so important for the application). Standard way - I have ViewModel with a property with get and set implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and binded this one to the Text property of the Entry in the Views that have BindingContext of the mentioned ViewModel.

**need:**

Need binding to be executed (set property called) after the user go out of the Entry (click somewhere outside of the control or push TAB on keyboard). Default binding situation is that the binding is executed every keystroke the user do.

**example:**

If the user enters Entry and make input `1234` the set funciton on binded property in VM is fired 4 times, after every key pushed. I want it to fire just once after user ends with this Entry control.

**tries:**

Seems to be so basic... I already tried:

- find equivalent for `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"` (like we did in WPF)
- trying to use UpdateSourceEventName with `Completed` or `Unfocused`
- trying to manually update this binding - I have managed to catch the moment of the user leaving the Entry by checking second parameter of Unfocused event `private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e) { if(!e.IsFocused) { ...` but can't find equivalent to `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` (like we did in WPF), moreover on `sender as Entry` there is only `SetBinding` while nothing to get it...
- googled for almost 2 hours...

**EDIT: my workaround:**

I have managed to do crazy workaround like that:

- In my ViewModel I have done an additional property like ValueTemp which is binded to Text property of the Entry. The View is binded to this property.
- The old Value property from ViewModel is binded to Placeholder (must be binded to something to trigger getter, maybe I would do multibinding with converter or some non visible label) and during its getter I am setting the value to ValueTemp
- During Entry_Unfocused event I am acquiring ValueTemp and setting it to the old Value property. Somehow Completed does not trigger in my case.
- There are some tricks for proper PropertyChanged and two way synchronization.
- In reality my code is much more complex, that is why it is hard to put some code here. But in general I use an additional property in VM and bind it for Views purposes, when user finishes editing it I set its value to my proper property so it can be processed later on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry.completed?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However not really sure how I can limit the updates of the binded property in VM by this? This Completed event is only an alternative regarding Unfocused event and checking e.IsFocused of its parameter, right?

Comment: By the way - not sure why, but Entry_Completed event is not hit after I enter `1234` and push TAB button. Anyway... even if it fires... how I manually update the binding to VM and how I limit its updates until this moment? Best Regards

Comment: I would not use binding on the Entry, instead just update the VM manually when the event fires

Comment: What is the real problem with this binding? Any performance issues?

Comment: @Jason the problem is that the real construction of this system is much more complex. In short - in runtime I consume xml files and based on them I am creating VM, which later on are displayed as views via data template selectors... and on top of that each VM have corresponding registry which is then passed to the IoT kind of device... So the views are not predefined, so I do not know the properties which are going to be binded before runtime. Thanks for the answer anyway :) Kind regards!

Comment: @SirRufo Actually performance is not a matter in this application. The problem is that based on the user input external IoT kind of devices are set up. And these devices are managing the buildings. Application has also something called online mode which is going live. I have plugged everything to be automatically working: user input -> view -> view model -> registry model -> communication protocol -> external device. But MAUI.NET dissapointed for the first time seriously. That is great framework imo, but not giving "LostFocus" in binding. I am sure this would be needed in more cases, also perf

Comment: My workaround is that each my VM has an additional properties - Value and ValueTemp. When user ends input then event Unfocused reassign value from ValueTemp to Value. There is hard way to plug it other way, but eventually I did... MAUI.NET is great, but dissapointed me so much this time. Please people from MS consider fix UpdateSourceEventName or give back LostFocus binding way!

Comment: instead of complaining about it here, it would be much more helpful to file an issue in the MAUI github

Comment: You are right @Jason sorry for a moment of frustration. In long-term / for .NET society issue on github would be more helpful, however from my own perspective is not. As I am quite sure they would not change it quickly, and my client would not wait a year for .NET, so weirdo workarounds are needed... Anyway there are already issues regarding this topic: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/9058 or https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9527 and year after.... nothing happened... So from one hand you are right, sorry for my behaviour, from the other please understand a bit of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a behavior for this as described in the [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors#net-maui-behaviors).

In this behavior you declare an attached property for the binding with your ViewModel and subscribe to the `Unfocused` event of the entry to update the attached property.

```cs
public class EntryLostFocusBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
        "Text",
        typeof( string ),
        typeof( EntryLostFocusBehavior ),
        null,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: TextPropertyChanged );

    public static string GetText( Entry entry ) => (string)entry.GetValue( TextProperty );
    public static void SetText( Entry entry, string value ) => entry.SetValue( TextProperty, value );

    private static void TextPropertyChanged( BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue )
    {
        var entry = (Entry)bindable;
        entry.Placeholder = newValue as string;
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo( Entry bindable )
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo( bindable );
        bindable.Unfocused += Entry_Unfocused;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom( Entry bindable )
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom( bindable );
        bindable.Unfocused -= Entry_Unfocused;
    }

    private void Entry_Unfocused( object sender, FocusEventArgs e )
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;
        SetText( entry, entry.Text );
    }
}
```

and use this in your view

```xml
<Page ...
      xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyMauiApp.Behaviors"
      ...>

  <Entry b:EntryLostFocusBehavior.Text="{Binding Value1}">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
          <b:EntryLostFocusBehavior />
      <Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>

  <Entry b:EntryLostFocusBehavior.Text="{Binding Value2}">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
          <b:EntryLostFocusBehavior />
      <Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>

</Page>
```

And thats it for the view/viewmodel. No code-behind, no additional properties.